# Can I see all photos of me on Facebook which are not listed on my profile?

Tags: photos, facebook

On Facebook, it's possible to do a "Remove from profile" action on my photos. What happens to the photos that I do that for? Can I later undo the action, or review them?

Comment: Are you referring to Facebook Timeline or the old Facebook profile?

Comment: I don't have timeline yet, so the old profile - though I guess I'll want to know what happens in Timeline, too, since that's coming soon.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is different from 'Delete post/photo' action. I vaguely remember that if I clicked on `Remove from profile` option, it would just remove the photo from the profile, not from the photo album itself [whichever album you uploaded to]. You can try it out.

You can't undo or review the action.

In Facebook Timeline though, you have the option to `Hide from Timeline`. Once you click `Hide from Timeline`, a button `Undo` appears in case you would want to undo the action - but only for that instance. Once you refresh the page, the button does not appear.

However, on the Facebook Timeline profile page, there's an `Activity Log` button. If you click on it, it allows you to review all your activities on Facebook and it gives you three options for every activity:

- Featured on Timeline
- Allowed on Timeline
- Hidden on Timeline

If you have hidden something on your Timeline, you can undo that here. Or if you allowed something, you can hide it, etc. .

Comment: What if the photos are in albums which I don't own? Do I remain tagged in them, even if they are removed from my profile?

Comment: I don't think removing the photo from profile removes the tag unless you chose the action `Remove Tag`.